# How to Fetch only Some Objects Matching a Bool Attribute

Tags: iphone, core-data, properties, boolean, nsfetchrequest

Every time I fetch objects from the database I get all objects. Now, I have to fetch and show in a table view only some of the objects stored in the database.

To do this, I've thought to add a new attribute in my entity, a BOOL attribute so I can fetch only objects that have this attribute's value equal to YES or NO depending situations.

Is it possible to do something like this?

I've found the `-setPropertiesToFetch:` method of `NSFetchRequest` class that can be useful but I don't know if I can use it to see the different value of a BOOL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you just want to use a predicate.  The [NSPredicate Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSPredicate_Class/Reference/NSPredicate.html) gives a good idea of how to use them.  Basically, it adds a filter to your results.  For example, let's say you have a core data object with an attribute `myBool` which is a BOOL (but stored as NSNumber, of course).  To filter your results based on that, you would use something like this

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"myBool == %@", [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
```

then continue as normal.  This will return just the results that have the `myBool` value as YES.

That being said, if you are using the request to simply populate a tableView, you might be better off using the [NSFetchedResultsController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsController_Class/Reference/Reference.html).  A great tutorial on how to implement it can be found [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/999/core-data-tutorial-how-to-use-nsfetchedresultscontroller).

Comment: +1 I would add that you shouldn't have to add an attribute to an entity in the data model just so it will display. Entity properties should closely mimic the properties of the real-world objects, events or conditions the app deals with. For example, if you're app deals with people and you have a `Person` object, you would have a `firstName` property but not a `displayInThirdView` property. The first is an attribute of a real person but rhe latter is an implementation detail that does not belong in the data model.

Comment: Thank you so much... This works so great ;) I have to use predicates more often :D